# The oauth state was missing or invalid. How to fix?

Tags: asp.net, rest, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to send an OAuth request but I keep getting this error after choosing an account.

This is what I've tried, I read that the state is supposed to be randomly generated, but I still get the error.

```
 public static string GetOauthUri(string state, string ClientId)
        {
            StringBuilder sbUri = new StringBuilder(OauthUri);
            sbUri.Append("client_id=" + ClientId);
            sbUri.Append("&redirect_uri=" + RedirectUri);
            sbUri.Append("&response_type=" + "code");
            sbUri.Append("&scope=" + Scopes);
            Random random = new Random();
            string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            sbUri.Append("&state=" + new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray()));
            sbUri.Append("&access_type=" + "offline");
            sbUri.Append("&approval_prompt=" + "force");

            return sbUri.ToString();
        }
```

Even if I omit the state, I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you check [Oauth2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1), you can see that your request should look like this:

> ```
> GET /authorize?response_type=code&client_id=s6BhdRkqt3&state=xyz
>         &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb HTTP/1.1
>     Host: server.example.com
> ```

The state should be passed ( step (A) ) from the *client* then to the *user-agent* then to the *authorization* server. I suspect that the state should be generated by the client in your implementation.

> The authorization server validates the request to ensure that all
> required parameters are present and valid. If the request is valid,
> the authorization server authenticates the resource owner and obtains
> an authorization decision (by asking the resource owner or by
> establishing approval via other means).

It is highly probable that the server implementation checks for a particular state input, but that you are unaware of which one. You should get info from the service developers/maintainers for this. If they didn't have the time to implement the functionality properly, they might have used the example value of the RFC 'xyz' as a dummy parameter value.

Try also to change the parameters order to match the RFC example and avoid multiple scopes, since a concatenation of scopes using a space could sometime be misinterpreted by the server by "cuting" the other key=values pairs.